# Javascript variable scoping issue in geocoding

Tags: javascript, variables, geocoding

When I use Geocoding APIs on my code, I assigned **var latitude** as an global(line 20), and in **function geocoder**, variable works. But in line 35, it throws out error as **0**. Even though it works in **function** scope.

```
14 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
15 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
16 <script type="text/javascript">
17 
18 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
19 var longitude = 0.0;
20 var latitude = 0.0;
21 
22 if (geocoder) {
23     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'Louvre Museum' }, function (results, status) {
24             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
25             longitude = results[0].geometry.location.nb;
26             latitude = results[0].geometry.location.ob;
27             console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
28             } 
29             else {
30             console.log('No results found: ' + status);
31             }
32             });
33 }
34 
35 console.log(latitude);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geocoder works asynchronous, so when you call console.log(latitude) the Geocoder hasn't finished yet and therefor not assigned a different value to latitude.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

To display your coordinates you could do something like:

```
    geocoder.geocode({
    'address': 'Louvre Museum'
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        longitude = results[0].geometry.location.nb;
        latitude = results[0].geometry.location.ob;
        console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
        document.getElementById('the_id_of_your_element').innerHTML = longitude + ',' + latitude;
    } else {
        console.log('No results found: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Then how should I solve this problem? When I moved brace '}' to end of line, it didn't work also.

Comment: In the function where you defined the latitude is the first moment you can use the value. What is it you are trying to do with it?

Comment: I tried to find a specific geographic position, in this case Louvre, and print out message its coordination.

Comment: I have updated my answer. See if you can do something with that.